# Unable to save AWS glue job getting headBucket: Forbidden: null erorr

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have created an AWS glue job in the north California region but when I am trying to update the code I get an error:

> Failed to update job
> [s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com] headBucket: Forbidden: null

Can someone please help me with the solution to this error?

[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qKV7.png)

I tried a lot of ways by giving the multiple permissions of glue access but nothing has worked so far.

below I am attaching the list of policies that I am using for my glue job

[LIst of policies that I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90tma.png)

Comment: What policies did you try to apply? And did you still get the exact error? Can you update your question to reflect your attempts please?

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary,

I have attached the list of policies that I am using, could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary,

for more details please follow the GitHub link of this issue:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/discussions/4498

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the solution please follow the below steps:

1. Go to the S3 bucket.
2. On the left-hand navigation pan will get an option called "**Access Points**" Click on that.
3. then select the region in which we need to save the job of AWS glue. eg. For the above question, we need to select "**US West (N. California) us-west-1**"

**Note**: Make sure you will have all the appropriate policies attached to your role for the Glue access.